# Replacing multiple string intervals in R

Tags: r, gsub

I am currently working on a data sat which has two  header rows (The first one acting as overall category description and the second one containing subcategories. And it happens to be that both contain various `<text>` intervals. For example:

In the first row (column names of the data frame), i have a cell that contains:
- text... `<span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">in the office</span> on the activities below. Total must add up to 100%. <br /><br />`

The second row contains multiple cells with:
- text `<strong>`
- text `</strong>`

Now, I was able to work out of how to remove all `<text>` intervals in the second row through:
`data[1,] = gsub("<.*>", "", data[1,])`

However, for the column names row, if I use:
`colnames(data) = gsub("<.*>", "",colnames(data))`
I end up just with "text", which I don't want. Due to the fact, that I still want to have:
`text... in the office on the activities below. Total must add up to 100%`

If some one would have an idea of how to solve it. I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably pushing up hill to use regex to parse HTML. I would look into properly parsing this with the XML package if you have more detailed extractions than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you need by changing the regular expression you are using with the following:

```
colnames(data) <- gsub("<[^>]+>", "",colnames(data))
```

This will remove anything between opening and closing tags (including the tag). That should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex is *greedy* and is consuming everything in between the first opening bracket and last closing bracket.  One quick fix would be to make your regex non greedy by using `?`:

```
data[1,] = gsub("<.*?>", "", data[1,])
```

Note that using regex to parse HTML generally is not a good idea.  If you plan on doing anything with nested content then you should consider using an R package which can parse HTML content.

## Demo

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of the regex condition. As I am new, could you refer me a side where I can read upon the the condition for parsing HTML content?                                                                                                          It works perfectly when I change it from `data[1, ]` to `colnames(data)`

Comment: @ChristophP. Just search for it.  I am saying that if you had nested HTML tags then this regex would not work.  It only appears to work correctly now.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate that you took the time to help me.